# Ionic - Differences between setRoot and push

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a doubt about the behavior of setRoot and push. If I'm not wrong, I got the same result with these methods. The method push will push a page into a stack and setRoot method will change the root page.
When should I use one or the other?? Is there any difference in performance or good practices?

Answer (score 1):

If the view you want to switch to is a child of the current view, or if you want the ability to navigate back to the previous view from the new view, you should push and if the view you are switching to is not a child of the current view, or it is a different section of the application, then you should instead change the root page.